# I need to read a remote file with logs from a tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, remote-access

I need to read a remote file with logs from a tomcat

What is the most convenient way to do it if I have ssh access to the log folder ?

Comment: This isn't really a tomcat question, it's a more general question about how to read remote files

Answer (score 8):

[OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/) can read logs from remote server. It supports SFTP, FTP and Samba. It also provides remote file systems browser.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 3):

Use Editplus to connect to remote server via FTP/SSH.

Refresh the logs as and when you need to.

Comment: I connect Editplus over FTP to my remote servers. Also see http://editplus.info/wiki/Features#Integrated_FTP

Answer (score 2):

You can use log4j's Chainsaw V2 and a VFSLogFilePatternReceiver to parse and tail the log file using Jakarta Commons-VFS support for ssh.

Chainsaw page:
http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/

log4j 'companions' page:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/

The easiest way to get started with Chainsaw is check it out (svn) along with the extras, component and receivers 'companions', build them using maven.

Once Chainsaw is built, you can run the script in the appassembler/bin folder and configure Chainsaw with a receiver configuration that can tail the log file (see Chainsaw's Welcome tab/view example receiver configuration button for an example config file).