# Live web log viewer for tomcat catalina.out

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, log4j

With a standard webapp running in Tomcat with the Spring Framwork and Log4J logging to catalina.out I need to have a better access to logs than manual SSH and `tail -f catina.out`

I already know of some solution like logstash, ... but they require to send the log to a centralized server. I went through a lot of answers of various websites but none satisfies my needs. I just want to have access to the logs in a web browser on the same web server.

Is there any simple and straightforward way to do that ?

## Update

I want to to that because I cannot always SSH and `tail -f` the logs because of the firewall IP security. I need to be able to see these logs from anywhere as long as I have an internet access to such a secure live web console.

Comment: You could setup Apache to serve the folder where your tomcat logs are

Comment: @francescoforesti my browser is on my computer (Chrome or whatever) and the web server is on a distant host (in AWS cloud).

Comment: yep, I knew I misunderstood.. see the edit

Comment: @francescoforesti I don't want to serve a file. It would be too long to refresh. I need a live webpage viewer that appends new lines when they appear in the file. I'm surprised this is not a default feature of Log4j, such a basic feature.

Comment: understood.. maybe [this ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/9691/viewing-logs-on-a-remote-linux-server), or [this tomcat-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881854/i-need-to-read-a-remote-file-with-logs-from-a-tomcat) can help

Comment: @francescoforesti Already saw these subjects but thanks anyway. They are not web viewers. I'm looking for a live console in a web gui.

Comment: if you elaborate what makes **live console in web gui** better than **tail -f**, you may get more specific answers.

Comment: @elsadek SSH requires me to be on a specific IP due to firewall security. I need to have a secured web GUI to access the logs from anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried Logstash+ElasticSearch+Kibana? Kibana is a web GUI to view logs collected by Logstash and indexed by ElasticSearch (all 3 tools have to be installed directly on the web server box)

Comment: @xav it is way ahead of what I need. I'm just looking for a live web console. I dont need all these tools just to do that, don't you think ?

Comment: @singe31 Well, it depends on your needs (I, too, prefer lightweight and straight-forward tools in this case). If you only need to see raw text, then have you thought about writing a few lines of PHP that will read the end of your log file?

Comment: @xav I wanted it to be integrated in the existing app (Java with Spring framework) and be accessible with some url like domain/logs for example

Comment: Is remote logging, for example to a logstash/ElasticSearch instance, an option? If so, then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429377/how-can-i-integrate-tomcat6s-catalina-out-file-with-logstash-elasticsearch

Comment: @mp911de No I'm afraid it's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Give [logsniffer](http://www.logsniffer.com) a try. It's a simple standalone Java web application which can run on the same host. log4j log format is supported out of the box, just type in the conversion pattern and the logs will be parsed properly. You can tail, search and monitor the logs in real-time. Last but not least, logsniffer is open source.

*Disclaimer: This is my own project.*